# ON DELETE CASCADE is not working is in sqlite3 in ios

Tags: ios, sqlite, cascade, cascading-deletes

I created a .sqlite file in ios programatically like below by enabling pragma foreignkeys ON

```
    NSFileManager *theFileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([theFileManager fileExistsAtPath:[self getDatabasePath]] == NO)
    {
        char *theError;
        const char *databasePath = [[self getDatabasePath] UTF8String];
        const char *enableForienKey = [@"PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;" UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(databasePath, &mDatabase) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_exec(mDatabase, enableForienKey, NULL, NULL, &theError)!=SQLITE_OK)
            {
                DEBUGLOG(kCreateTableError,sqlite3_errmsg(mDatabase));
            }
            sqlite3_close(mDatabase);
        }
        else {
            DEBUGLOG(KFailedToCreateDBFile);
        }
    }
```

Pragma foreign key is enabling but, I created two tables like below with create queries including ON DELETE CASCADE
// First table Create query

```
   @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Session (sessionAppID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , sessionID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, userAppID INTEGER, deviceAppID INTEGER NOT NULL, sessionStartTime VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, sessionEndTime VARCHAR(255), sessionCreatedDateTime VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,sessionUpdatedDateTime VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, sessionFailureCount INTEGER NOT NULL,sessionStatus INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(userAppID) REFERENCES User(userAppID), FOREIGN KEY(deviceAppID) REFERENCES Device(deviceAppID))"
```

//Second table which is child of first table query

```
 @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EventLog (eventLogAppID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , eventGUID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, sessionAppID INTEGER NOT NULL , eventName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, eventGroupGUID VARCHAR(255), eventParentGUID VARCHAR(255), eventCategory INTEGER NOT NULL,eventStartTime VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, eventEndTime VARCHAR(255) ,eventDuration VARCHAR(255),eventType INTEGER NOT NULL,eventCreatedDateTime VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,eventUpdatedDateTime VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,eventFailureCount INTEGER NOT NULL,eventStatus INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(sessionAppID) REFERENCES Session(sessionAppID)ON DELETE CASCADE)"
```

On deleting the session record, Only session record is deleting eventLog records are not deleting, Can any one please help on this, what will be the problem.By the way I am using sqlite3 version 3.7.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable. Note that you need to enable foreign keys for each connection.

Presumably you are creating a new connection to perform the `delete` query. Update your code so every time you open a db connection, you set the pragma as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your great help,it's working If I replaced that enabling part to only delete query in particular class. But I want to know some thing more like, I don't know much about other technologies I saw in android they are just enabling foreign keys at Database creation by setting like this public void setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled (boolean enable)  and if I open firefox plugin also there are in DB setting only that enabling option will be there, but why in IOS even though its same sqlite why need to enable at the particular query.

Answer (score 0):

I was using singleton instance of SQLiteAsyncConnection in Xamarin.Forms, but anyways had to call "PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;" **before each DeleteAsync method call**. Calling it once after opening the connection didn't work for me. To sum up what @rmaddy and @Karthik Mitta tried to jointly say